# registration confirmation email

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Register(User user)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

 UserAPIController uApi = new UserAPIController(true);
                HttpResponseMessage response = uApi.Register(user, Request.QueryString["TeamId"]);
                if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Conflict)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("LanguageResource", "DuplicateEmailErrorMessage").ToString());
                    return View();
                }

                //Send Registration Email
                string EmailBodyStr = string.Empty;
                string EmailFrom = Helpers.CommonFunctions.GetApplicationSettingValue("SystemEmailId");
                string EmailSub = HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("LanguageResource", "EmailTemplate_Reistration_Subject").ToString();
                string userName = user.FullName;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName))
                {
                   userName = user.Email;
                }

                EmailBodyStr = HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("LanguageResource", "EmailTemplate_Registration_TeamLeader_Body").ToString();
                EmailBodyStr = EmailBodyStr.Replace("[UserFullName]", userName);
                string email = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Helpers.Encrypt.EncryptString(user.Email));
                EmailBodyStr = EmailBodyStr.Replace("[NavigationLink]", "<a href=" + "\"" + Helpers.CommonFunctions.GetApplicationSettingValue("ApplicationName") + "/User/Login?UserEmail=" + email + "\"" + ">click here</a>");
                if (EmailFrom != string.Empty)
                {
                    Helpers.Emailer.SendEmail(user.Email, EmailSub, EmailBodyStr, EmailFrom);
                }
                ModelState.AddModelError("", HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("LanguageResource", "SuccessfullRegistrationMessage").ToString());
     }

            return View(user);
        }
```

I have created a registration form in mvc4 in which the user get confirmation email once it get registered but its sending the same registration email two times. Above is the code which is used for registration confirmation.
Please let me know where is the problem in code and why its triggering same event two times.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `Register`, is it getting hit twice? What is the line `uApi.Register(user, Request.QueryString["TeamId"]);` doing? Does `SendEmail` have a bug in it?

Comment: There are quite a fair bit of custom codes which we have no visibility. For e.g ->
uApi.Register(user, Request.QueryString["TeamId"]); What's inside?

Comment: I Put the breakpoint  to register method and found that its hitting only one time. I checked my email and found that its coming via Sendgrid.info.